# How can I make Chrome application shortcuts start maximized?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Chrome no longer seems to open my application shortcuts (pinned to the Windows 7 taskbar) in a maximized window. I didn't used to have this problem -- in the past, I'd simply create a new application shortcut on the taskbar (e.g., Gmail, Google+), open the shortcut, maximize the window, close it, and Chrome would remember that I wanted that shortcut maximized next time. That's no longer the case. Seems like this functionality has been broken since Chrome 13 or 14. (At least on my system.)

My operating environment:

- Windows 7 x64 Ultimate
- Chrome 14.0.835.186 m
- Shortcuts are pinned to the Windows 7 taskbar

How can I make Chrome application shortcuts start maximized? I've tried most of the supposed solutions I could find ( [How to start Google Chrome with maximized window?](https://superuser.com/questions/276923/how-to-start-google-chrome-with-maximized-window) ), to no avail.

Adding `-start-maximized` or `--start-maximized` to the shortcut target command line works perfectly for my regular Chrome shortcut, but it doesn't seem to have any effect on application shortcuts.

Anyone know how to force application shortcuts to start maximized?

Comment: Your new to the site, so please read the [FAQs](http://superuser.com/faq "Super User FAQs")...  Your question really should be in three parts.  One for each Operating System.  when you say "at least on my system" what OS are you using? What operating system are you using?

Comment: I included my OS and Chrome version in the second sentence: "I'm running Windows 7 x64 Ultimate, Chrome 14.0.835.186 m". Was I supposed to put it somewhere else? I may be new to superuser, but I'm a long-time stackoverflow/stackexchange user :)

Comment: Did you try removing it from the taskbar, and dragging the working desktop shortcut down to the taskbar to pin it?

Comment: +1 for good question.   @Michael I apologize.  I thought you had written Ubuntu.  I'm very sorry and did not mean to offend you in any way.

Comment: @Rob: I don't have a working desktop shortcut. So far I've only been using pinned taskbar shortcuts. I haven't tried desktop shortcuts at all, in fact. Perhaps I should?

Comment: @wizlog: No offense taken! I appreciate any and all feedback, thanks for your response. In fact, I think I'll edit my question so the OS and Chrome version are more apparent.

Comment: @Michael You should... see my answer.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to post an answer, but I solved this: Add the command-line switch [`--app-window-size=9999,9999`](http://code.google.com/codesearch#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/common/chrome_switches.cc&exact_package=chromium&q=kAppWindowSize&type=cs&l=73) to make an the window take up the entire screen when Chrome is launched in application mode.

Answer (score 3):

I can not solve your problem directly, but I have the best workaround possible.

You can also create desktop shortcuts for other websites and apps you regularly use, even if they're not installed from the Chrome Web Store. Follow these steps:

1. Click the wrench icon [image: icon] on the browser toolbar.
2. Select Tools.
3. Select Create application shortcuts.
4. In the dialog that appears, choose where you'd like the shortcuts to be placed on your computer.
5. Click Create.
   -this guide to creating [Application shortcuts](http://www.google.com/support/chrome/bin/answer.py?answer=95710)
    has been copied from Google's support pages.

### Here is what your looking for...

1. **Right click** on the **shortcut** or menu item you use to **start** the program.
2. Now, click on **properties**.
3. Note the item labeled **Run** that's set to "Normal Window". Change that to "**Maximized**".

After this is done, you can drag and drop the shortcut to the start menu or taskbar and you should be fine.  I tried this with Windows Vista, and it worked great. I see no reason why this shouldn't work for Windows 7

Comment: @Michael -- If you would like a visual guide to preforming these steps, I will upload pictures to assist you.

Comment: This isn't working reliably on my system. It seems to fail if I have another Chrome window open that *isn't* maximized. Try this: Pin a regular Google Chrome shortcut to your taskbar. Open it, size it down (non-maximized), and close it. Reopen to confirm Chrome "remembers" your sized down preference. Now, create your application shortcut with the "start maximized" setting (it can be a desktop or taskbar app shortcut). Open the app with no Chrome windows open, and it starts maximized and works perfectly. But open the regular Chrome window first (unmaximized), then open the app, and it fails :(

Comment: Does anyone know if it's possible to remove the windows application frame when not in fullscreen? i.e. [this bit](http://content.screencast.com/users/GavinAtDatacom/folders/Jing/media/decf8e03-d8db-4157-8d3a-4bb462cfd9f8/2013-08-12_1148.png).

Answer (score 1):

Right click on the shortcut in the task bar, right click on the shortcut name, go to Properties, under Run: choose Maximized, hit OK.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. (Although you would think it would.) Unless something has changed (bug fix?) in the most recent release of Chrome. I'll check it out and report back.

Comment: Yes, confirmed, this does not work. Thanks for your response though. See my comment on the other answer. The issue I'm having occurs when you have another chrome window open that *isn't maximized*. With no Chrome windows open, a shortcut with "Maximized" set works just fine, but if you typically keep your Chrome browser non-maximized, the "Maximized" preference is completely ignored for application shortcuts.

Comment: It worked for me on Windows 7 Ultimate.